# Extract information from defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict that contains the calculation of the average position of number ( Euler problem )

```
[('1', 0.6923076923076923), ('0', 2.0), ('3', 0.2222222222222222),
 ('2', 1.0909090909090908), ('7', 0.0), ('6', 0.875), 
('9', 1.6923076923076923),('8', 1.3333333333333333)]
```

I'm trying to get this information into simple string instead of doing it manually from 0 - 2. 
The end result I'm looking for is something like

```
73162890
```

I don't know any good way to extracting them without using many if-else and for-loops.

Is there any simple and good way of doing this in python?

Comment: Are you trying to get them in order?

Comment: yes I want 7 to come first because it has the lowest value(0.0) for example and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your dict is `d`, then `items = d.items()` gives you a list of pairs, like you have. Once you have this list, you can sort it by the second element:

```
ordered = sorted(items, key=lambda (_, value): value) # Not Python 3

# or,
ordered = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[1])

# or,
import operator
ordered = sorted(items, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Once we have the list in sorted order, we just need to extract the strings from each one, and glue them all together:

```
result = ''.join(string for (string, _) in ordered)
```

(Note that I'm calling unused parameters `_`, there's nothing special about the `_` in a Python program.)

Comment: I've never seen tuple unpacking on the lhs of the colon in a `lambda` expression before ... Or in a function for that matter.  Who knew that `def func((a,b),c): ...` is actually valid syntax?  Learn something new every day ...

Comment: @mgilson It's [gone in Python 3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/), so don't get too used to it. :)

Comment: @Dougal -- I really can't think of any really good use-case for it, so I wasn't about to start ... It's still somewhat nifty though.

Comment: I used this one here "ordered = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[1])"
and wrote it down for future use :)

Answer (score 6):

```
In [36]: ''.join([key for key, val in sorted(data, key = lambda item: item[1])])
Out[36]: '73162890'
```

---

Explanation:

[This sorts the data](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) according to the second value for each item in `data`.

```
In [37]: sorted(data, key = lambda item: item[1])
Out[37]: 
[('7', 0.0),
 ('3', 0.2222222222222222),
 ('1', 0.6923076923076923),
 ('6', 0.875),
 ('2', 1.0909090909090908),
 ('8', 1.3333333333333333),
 ('9', 1.6923076923076923),
 ('0', 2.0)]
```

Now we can collect the first value in each item using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [38]: [key for key, val in sorted(data, key = lambda item: item[1])]
Out[38]: ['7', '3', '1', '6', '2', '8', '9', '0']
```

And join these items into a string [using `''.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
In [39]: ''.join([key for key, val in sorted(data, key = lambda item: item[1])])
Out[39]: '73162890'
```

Comment: Nice explanation… but why write an explicit lambda to do the job of the built-in `operator.itemgetter`?

Comment: @abarnert: a lambda is more explicit (as you pointed out!), easier to read, and not much slower. It's a personal preference though.

Comment: Just remember that Guido hates `lambda`, and TOOWTDI is a core part of the Python philosophy. So one day, he will take it away, and you'll have to rewrite all that code that you wrote based on your personal preference instead of his.